# How to pass params in React Native Navigation for the goBack() function

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I know this is a stupid question.
I have a component lets call it `Component` that is used in several screens for Example `Screen1`,`Screen2`,...
And in the `Component` I am navigating to a new Screen when the user click a button, lets call it `ImagePicker`.

my Question is how do I go back and pass a parameter( in this case image data) and get it back in the `Component`

I tried using `navigation.goBack({img: image})` but that didn't work. I also can't use `navigation.navigate('Screen')` since my functions are in the `Component` component.

So what is the best solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 4):

We cannot pass any params to the goBack method.

If we have to do so then, we can use the navigate method to navigate to the back screen, and using this method we can pass the params to the previous screen.

For ex.

```
navigation.navigate('PrevScreenName', {key: value})
```

Check out the official docs for the react-navigation.

[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Answer (score 0):

In the component code, I would pass along a callback function to the image picker screen

```
handleImageData = (data) =>
{
   // do whatever
}
...
navigation.navigate('ImagePickerScreen',{mycallback:this.handleImageData});
```

and then in the screen code just call it like

```
this.props.route.params.mycallback(data);
navigation.goBack();
```

Comment: But I have to implement this function in all Screens correct ?

Comment: I created a callback function but I cant pass it in navigation

Comment: I misunderstood your question, but the same idea applies. You can pass in the callback from the component to the screen as in `navigation.navigate('ImagePicker',{mycallback:handleImageData}`

Comment: In the image picker screem, you'd reference it like `this.props.route.params.mycallback(imageData)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well, just do
`navigation.navigate('Screen', {img: image})`
instead of `navigation.goBack({img: image})` and it should work

Comment: But I have several screens that navigate through the Component. So, I cant call one by its name

Comment: In this case two solutions : 
you add a param when you navigate to the picker to tell it where to navigate back
or you mount your picker in a full screen modal and add a callback as proposed by Mike M